# Sent pushes in Parse is 0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So there are many questions and answers out there but none of them are working for me. When I go to the parse dashboard I have 2 devices in everyone, but when I send a push it says pushes sent 0. They are both iOS devices and I'm using the push portal with a development certificate.p12.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not receive notification on your device, you may have forgotten to call the method `initializeNotificationServices` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func initializeNotificationServices() -> Void {
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [ .Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    print("initialize")

    // This is an asynchronous method to retrieve a Device Token
    // Callbacks are in AppDelegate.swift
    // Success = didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
    // Fail = didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}



func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
    print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    print("didReceiveRemoteNotification")

    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

And method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Parse.setApplicationId("MyID",
            clientKey: "MyKey")

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var pushPayload = false

        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        print("register")

    } else {
        let types = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound])
    }

    initializeNotificationServices()

    return true
}
```

Comment: I'm getting installations in the database so it is hitting the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken. When I try to push the notifications is says zero sent.